# Mapped keyboard shortcuts that generate text responses (macros maybe)

Tags: windows, keyboard, python, key-binding

I've got a seemingly simple idea where I would press a combination of keys (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>) and paste a previously written(and saved) response on wherever I'm typing. This is meant to work in a Windows Server or Win 7 environment. So far the idea I had come up with (but can't actually implement) was writing a little program in Python(since thats the only language I know) that can run silently in the background and calls upon specific texts from a location I've saved them to, whenever I press the designated key combo. The only issue (besides the code, which I suck in) is that I want to have it work even when I'm in a VDI (virtual server). Or perhaps there's a macro I can write that can achieve this? Or something already made that can do the job? Any helpful suggestions would be great!

Comment: Yea thanks guys, autohotkey is exactly what I wanted!!! Can't rep yet but I would if I could

Answer (score 2):

If going with **Autohotkey** get its newest release from "The AutoHotkey Foundations" home Page at http://ahkscript.org

AutoHotkey (AHK) is a free, open-source macro-creation and automation software for Windows, that over time evolved into a full-fledged scripting language.

3 simple examples

### A Hotkey

```
^!Z:: ; Ctrl+Alt+Z becomes a hotkey to type a pre defind text or keys:
Send Sincerely,{Enter}John Smith
return
```

### Or a Hotstring

```
:*:btw::by the way ; auto expands to "by the way" when "btw" is typed
```

### Or a remapping

```
a::b ; remaps the "a" key to the "b" key
```

most up to date documentation http://ahkscript.org/docs/AutoHotkey.htm

Answer (score 0):

Most common tool I know for this is AutoHotKey

Ref: http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: perhaps explain a little more why AHK might work well for this?

Comment: because it's designed to do exactly that? It's so straight forward and I don't know what else to explain.

Comment: For new users the strange syntax of autohotkey can seem odd, it would be beneficial to provide a brief example and potentially a link to the documentation for explanation purposes. Simply saying "use that" is not considered a particularly good answer.